# Unable to build React Native app for iOS Simulator with Swift 5.3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I have been trying to build a react native codebase for a number of hours now and battling Xcode and what seems to be the entire iOS ecosystem. I found that when I built my project I am using a proprietary 3rd party pod that has been compiled using Swift 5.3.0 however I am using Xcode 12 with Swift 5.3.1. I was getting an error saying that the library could not be used with 5.3.1 since it was compiled with 5.3.0 so I downloaded the [Swift 5.3.0 toolchain for Xcode](https://swift.org/download/#releases) and installed it. After setting the 5.3.0 version to my active toolchain and rebuilding the project I have received the following error:

```
Could not determine version of clang to find its Address Sanitizer library: /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-5.3-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
```

I'm unsure what the next steps are to resolve this and haven't been able to find much online. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Run the Terminal guy to see what is the Swift version on your system, first.

Comment: @ElTomato
# swift -version

Apple Swift version 5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.0.41 clang-1200.0.32.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0